# Save value of input to textfile on submit?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a website for fun where the user enters something into two `<input>` elements in a form, presses submit, and then the text is logged to a `.txt` file, then the user is sent to a page for confirmation.

Is this possible to do with a form, and does it require javascript?

The basic structure of something like this would be:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats possible without javascript.

You need to give each `input` a `name` and replace `button` with `input`.

Here is a start:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both fields are set
        $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 
        file_put_contents('test.log',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX); // log to test.log (make sure that file is writable (permissions))
        header('Location: http://www.google.com/search?q='.$txt); // google as example (use your confirmation page here)
        exit();
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

You can use `$_POST['field1']` and `$_POST['field2']` to get the values and log them.

**FILE_APPEND** is used to add new content to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

**LOCK_EX** is used to aquire a write lock for the file (in case multiple users post at the same time)

Comment: Why does the `button` need to be replaced with an `input`? Also, how would the actual posting work? You have `<pre>` in your code, what does that do for the posting?

Comment: You can also use a `button` i guess (never did this). `<pre>` is just to make the output of `print_r` a little nicer.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, how would that get actually written to a file? I was thinking something like... `$txt = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w'); fwrite($fh, $_POST); fclose($fh);` ?

Comment: That works for the logging, but does not work for the redirect. I get the infamous "Cannot modify header information" error. Also, I figured out how to write to a file a little differently, but I like the way you posted. My way was... http://snipt.org/ugihe8

Comment: You have to make sure that there is no other output before the `<?php` containing the `header()` function, not even a single space. Thats why i moved the php code infront of the form.

Comment: Ah, this works now. Thank you! Would my way be a bad way of doing it though?

Comment: Your example does not lock the file, which means that two concurrent `fwrite`s (from 2 users at the same time) could corrupt the file. See: http://php.net/flock